# Proper node.js abstractions to prevent race conditions when accessing ethereum blockchain

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, race-condition, web3js

I am using web3 version `1.0.0-beta.27` where all accesses to the blockchain will be asynchronous, clearly this opens up the possibility of race conditions, ie:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");     

// connect to etherum blockchain
var ether_port = 'http://localhost:8545'
var web3       = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ether_port));


// this is how we set the value, note there is the possiblity of race condidtions here
var accounts = []

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accts){
    console.log("printing account: ", accts)
    accounts = accts
})

// observe race condition
console.log("assert race condition: ", accounts[0])
```

The last line above is contrived, it is there to demonstrate that I would like to use `accounts` after it has been evaluated. Ie, eventually I would like modify/read the blockchain from a front end `express.js` web app or even a mobile app, so in the interest of being rigorous, what are the common tools in `node.js` to ensure race conditions never occur? Do these tools exist? If not what are some common practices. I am new to `node.js` as well.

Comment: Do you really mean "race conditions" or you are just asking generically about "asynchronous timing issues".  Race conditions typically mean something different.

Comment: @jfriend00 I meant "asynchronous timing issues". I apologize for the vague statement.

Comment: Then, please edit your question to replace "race conditions" with a better description of what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to not attempt to directly store the data because code trying to access the data has no idea when it's valid due to the uncertain nature of asynchronous results.  So, instead you store the promise and any code that wants access to the data, just uses `.then()/.catch()` on the promise.  This will always work, regardless of the async timing.  If the data is already there, the `.then()` handler will be called quickly.  If the data is not yet there, then the caller will be in line to be notified when the data arrives.

```
let accountDataPromise = web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accts){
    console.log("printing account: ", accts)
    return accts;
});

// then, elsewhere in the code
accountDataPromise.then(accts => {
    // use accts here
}).catch(err => {
    // error getting accts data
});
```

FYI, assigning data from a `.then()` handler to a higher scoped variable that you want to generally use in other code outside the promise chain is nearly always a sign of troublesome code - don't do it.  This is because other code outside the promise chain has no idea when that data will or will not be valid.